# Button onClick Event Handler Never Fires in Chrome Only

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, event-handling

I am working on an old ASP.NET WebForms application that has an .aspx page with the following control:

```
<asp:Button ID="Budget_Approve" OnClick="Budget_Approve_Click" runat="server"
Visible="True" Width="100" Height="30" Text="Approve"></asp:Button>
```

The `Budget_Approve_Click` event handler is never being hit, and I am trying to determine why. I noticed when the page loads, this code gets executed to add some inline js to the `onclick` attribute:

```
Budget_Approve.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm_approve();");
```

The HTML that gets rendered:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$mainContent$Budget_Approve" value="Approve"
onclick="return confirm_approve();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$mainContent$Budget_Approve&quot;, 
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"
id="ctl00_mainContent_Budget_Approve" style="height:30px;width:100px;">
```

So when I click, I expect `confirm_approve()` to be executed. If it returns `true`, I expect a postback and for my event handler to fire. Debugging in Chrome, I find that `confirm_approve()` does indeed return `true`:

[image: javascript code]

However, the postback never happens, and the `Budget_Approve_Click` event handler never gets hit. Why not?

**Edit:** I tried removing the line that adds the inline javascript code entirely. However, still no postback. The following HTML is rendered for the button:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$mainContent$Budget_Approve" 
value="Approve"
onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$mainContent$Budget_Approve&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"
id="ctl00_mainContent_Budget_Approve" style="height:30px;width:100px;" />
```

**Update:** Discovered that the postback **does work** in IE, but still not Chrome. Are there any browser-specific settings or issues that could potentially cause this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I would just work around it with this:

```
Budget_Approve.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if (!confirm_approve()) return false;");
```

Comment: thx for the input. tried it, but still nothing. i even tried removing this line entirely, but no change in results. seems there may be a bigger issue..

Comment: @mhornfeck - well what html was generated?  Can you edit it back into your answer

Comment: posted results to original question

Comment: @mhornfeck - so you're no longer messing with the button at all, and no postback?  Odd.  Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: No errors in the console. But, I tried running the page in IE (instead of Chrome) and it _does_ postback. Now, to find an explanation for that..

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
Budget_Approve.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if (!confirm_approve()) return false;");
```

Comment: It's exactly the same as the @Adam Racki's answer.

Comment: They must have been typing at the same time

Comment: We were off by a minute - he didn't copy me

Comment: Yes it may be. I don't offend @Naeem Sarfraz but just somewhat curious!

Answer (score -1):

Check if your button is disabled somehow.

$("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", "disabled");

If something like this happens, Chrome will have an incomplete POST request.
ASP.NET will not fire the server side events.